# Translate html file and save it

Tags: html, browser, language-translation

Many web browsers has translation extensions but all of them can translate web page in viewing time, but i am looking for any tool that can translate content of html file and replace it instead of original content.

Comment: Why not just have as many HTML files as languages you want to be displayed? And then redirect on the language corresponding on the one used by your visitor. Or, better, use your back-end language to populate your HTML with the corresponding language, so you only have 1 file

Comment: I need a copy of my html file in other languages, but not for publishing on web. it is statically needs for  presenting few ideas.

Comment: How many languages do you need? If it's like English - Spanish - Italian, just create 3 files with the translations in it. The downside is if you need more languages, this method is not really convenient

Comment: For start i need for 5 Languages.

Comment: I read your question again, and ... basically you're looking for a translator, it's not even a development problem

Comment: Yes, but i need it for developing. i need few copy of one static html file.

Comment: So, copy paste your text in a translator, such as Google Translator, or translate it yourself if you can do so, and then paste the result on a file, let's say file-english.html

Comment: Any translator has own limitation count of words to translating. and sometimes they are not working correctly, for example they translates attribute values(e.g class="My" becomes to class="ma"). and Document translators are not free ware.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Cloud Translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/) can do this. It's not free, and you need to write code to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, Yes yesterday i tired work with Google Cloud Translation api , but because of some reasons i can't buy it.

Answer (score 0):

I just used Chromium: loaded the webpage, Chromium offered me to translate it immediately. The translated result I was able to "save as" under "tools" in the menu.